# Different CloudPage Domain to the one connected to the SAP?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, sap, sender-authentication-package, cloudpagesurl

Is it possible to have more than one branded URL for CloudPages besides the one with the SAP?
Example:
URL = cloudpage1/brand1.domain.com - SAP
URL = cloudpage2/brand2.domain.com - NO SAP
URL = cloudpage3/brand3.domain.com - NO SAP

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. We had a similar use case and we have been told by the support and our account manager that this is not possible. You must stick with a single domain on CloudPages.

Comment: Is this still a limitation? I have a need of utilizing multiple private domains for different cloudpages.

Comment: @McdonaldZip it still a limitation.

Comment: thank you. one more question for clarification: we can enable SAP for IP + domain. additionally, we can add more private domains for use within the account, but we can only use the SAP domain for cloudpages? Any differences with BUs?

Comment: oh thank you, I thought we could use 1 SAP for all BUs

Comment: @McdonaldZip Sorry, I meant to say that you can only have one SAP per BU. You can share one SAP accross multiple accounts. Check out this link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_sap.htm&type=5

Comment: thanks, that makes sense!